# Does using a specialized library mean I have experience in that field?

Tags: resume, software-industry, work-experience

For example, I have a project where I used [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) to drive the physics in my C++ project. Does this mean I have physics programming experience and could I put it on my CV/Resume?

I'm a graduate with programming experience and I'm currently writing my CV/Resume, looking for a job in software development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For example, I have a project where I used Bullet Physics to drive the
>   physics in my C++ project. Does this mean I have physics programming
>   experience and could I put it on my CV/Resume?

It means that you have used the library, i would say that you have SOME experience. And point that out.

Because if you put that you have experience using Bullet Physics than potential recruiter will definitely ask you the question about that topic. And if your answer does not indicate to them that you really have experience in that field, you can almost say that you did not get the job. Altho if you put SOME experience than recruiter will ask question differently without so high expectation level. So you only show that you have experience and maybe earn some extra points for yourself.

Regarding if you actually should mention that, than answer is yes, if it is relevant. CV or Resume is the place you let the recruiter understand what you can do, what you have done, and what you want to do. If required job needs understanding about Bullet Physics than definitely mention that.

Update:

Considering comment there are few aspects that is important, which i did not mention in my answer. If you using library that uses physics programming than if you want to add that to you resume, be prepared that recruiters will ask about you knowledge about programming and physics in general. So if you don't have strong understanding about thous things than adding Bullet Physics mention that you have worked with this library without any extender knowledge about physics or/and programming concept that is used.

Comment: Anything you put on your resume, you may get asked detailed questions about. If someone claimed to me that they had Physics programming experience, I would ask about physics concepts as well as programming concepts if that was as key component of what I was hiring for. Someone who knows how to use the library without the technical knowledge of the field is a worse hire than someone who knows physics but doesn't know the tool.

Answer (score 2):

As a fellow software developer, if someone puts the qualification "physics programmer" on their resume I would expect them to know the fundamental aspects of physics simulation.

Using a library is an entirely separate thing, as you can use the library without understanding the fundamental concepts of the library. It's entirely possible for someone to use Ogre3D (a popular graphics library) to render out a simple scene for a project, but to say that they know the workings of Ogre3D would probably be a stretch at that point.

IMO for a resume, it's only worth putting down the technologies that you actually understand quite well. Alternatively if it was for a specific company, or a project within the company, I might list it under my experience with that company.

The best place for this sort of thing, especially when it comes down to personal or hobby work, would be the Cover Letter. Here is an except from a cover letter that actually got me a job:

> I have been working independently on a video game project over the past 2 years in C++. I have utilized Ogre3D for my graphics, and I implemented in physics via Bullet with a custom wrapper, as well as audio via the open-source stb_vorbis. I have prepared several demonstrations of my work as a hobbyist programmer, and you can view my portfolio at -redacted-.